# How Can I Set up Web Server On My Computer Android Project

Tags: android, database, authentication

I developed an application on Android which take user informations(SignUp) and these informations are inserted an db file like .db  .After that , I made LogIn in same application , which takes information about user from .db file and decides LogIn is allright or not. Thus far , everything is allright. However as you know this application is local.I want to connect web server because when I set up my app to another phone I want to take information.Can I set up web server in my own computer to try is my app working ? How can I do that on my own computer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to configure a local server and an api to make it work.

Use any webserver, XAMP,LAMP,tomcat,ect. create a data base using the phpMyadmin from your browser and also a user name to use by your application.

Use the URL like localhost/myfolder/../api.php to get the api which interacts to our application.

for interaction with the api , you can use http post.

Comment: Thanks for your replying , Now I set up it on my computer (Ubuntu 13.10) , I have API to login-signup operations , signup functions create a user.db folder on /data/data/com.example.app/databases path.For instance, I have 4 phones (X,Y) I signup a user from X phone , after that I want to Login on Y phone THAT user. How can I? I know this is basic question-problem but basics are big solutions,Thanks.

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/
this link helps me understand my basic problem. Thanks @user3751548

Answer (score 0):

Use this:
Xampp include apache-webserver, mysql server, php.
http://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/

Comment: Thank you , I am researching this now.